# Cómo hacer un insert de cálculos matemáticos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

quisiera hacer una inserción de cálculos matemáticos en una columna que tengo en mi base de datos

Quiero calcular el 70% de dos calificaciones

pero no sé como seria la estructura de la sentencia

Yo realicé la siguiente sentencia a través de una consulta en php con ella consigo que me muestre el 70% del valor de las dos calificaciones, ahora bien quiero que ese resultado se INSERTE en mi TABLA en la COLUMNA que tiene como nombre 70%. No sé si logro explicarme

```
$ghc_70 = number_format(round(($ghc_1+$ghc_2)/2)*0.70,1); (GHC es la materia),"
```

YO QUISIERA QUE ME CALCULE EL 70% DEL PROMEDIO DE LA MATERIA Y EL RESULTADO SEA INSERTADO EN LA TABLA EN LA COLUMNA 70%

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: igual a cualquier otra sentencia.. cada columna que agregues a tu select puede ser lo que vos quieras.. inclusive la suma de otras columnas...

Comment: saludos @gbianchi yo tengo en mi php la siguiente sentencia que me hace el cálculo que deseo.   round(($ghc_1+$ghc_2)/2)*0.70,1); (GHC es la materia), hora lo que quiero que el resultado lo lleve a la columna en mi tabla

Comment: El código y las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. En los comentarios no se entiende el código y es más para quienes van a intentar responder, que te pregunten cosas. Cosas que puedes responder EDITANDO la pregunta. No sabemos cuál es el problema al insertar el valor que calculaste ni la tabla destino

Comment: @AlbertoCarrasquero tienes la columna que recibirá al porcentaje creada? de ser así solo tienes que usar el `INSER INTO`

Comment: Saludos @lsanchezo
 , si la tengo creada, lo que no estoy claro como seria la estructura de la sentencia

Comment: pero si ya lo tenes calculado, solo es update de esa fila con ese valor en la columna.. que cosas intentaste y no te funcionaron?

Comment: Que te parece si editas tu pregunta agregando una captura de pantalla de tu tabla donde se aprecien los campos, si es que la tienes creada

Comment: No, disculpa. Seguimos viendo un valor calculado en PHP pero no se entiende nada del problema al insertar.

Comment: inserte o se actualice la fila?? son dos cosas muyyyy distintas....

Comment: Saludos @gbianchi en la actualidad la de 70% esta vacía, al menos que coloque esos cálculos manualmente, seria INSERTAR

Comment: no.. seria ACTUALIZAR.. insertar, es agregar una nueva fila.. actualizar, es tomar una fila que tiene valores, y cambiar algunos de ellos, inclusive esos que son nuevos y estan vacios...

Comment: entonces, usas una instruccion UPDATE, donde le decis que campo actualizar, y con que valor.. como el valor sale de la misma fila, podes hacer los calculos directamente en el SQL....

Comment: OK @gbianchi y  la estructura es así  UPDATE nombre-de-la-tabla
SET nombre-de-la-columna = valor[, nombre-de-la-columna=valor]
[WHERE condición]

Comment: exactamente.. lo probaste?

Comment: Seria de este modo    UPDATE EMG_1B_3 SET 70 = (cast_p)*70/100 WHERE id=doc